# Reinitializing an Observable object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I would like to have the ability to reinitialize an Observable object.
I don't know if "reinitialize" is the corrent term, but what I mean by that is that I would like to refresh the data

1. without creating a new Observable object, and
2. without creating new subscriptions (existing subscriptions to the existing Observable object should work seamlessly)

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {
  private url = 'http://mydummydomain.com/api/entries';
  private data$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.data$ = this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
      shareReplay(1)
    );
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.data$;
  }
  
  reloadData() {
    // TODO:
    // Refresh data from the url
    // Theoretically this should be a function with no input parameters and no return value
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
refresh$ = new Subject<void>();
data$ = this.refresh$.pipe(startWith(null), switchMap(() => this.http.get(this.url)), shareReplay(1));


reloadData() {
  refresh$.next();
}
```

Comment: I will be doing a little more testing before I mark this as the solution, but it seems to be working correctly, thanks

Comment: Can this approach be integrated in the first code sample, too? That is a more generic one, because that does not involve Angular libraries at all. I tried to modify that based on your code sample, but it did not work correctly. Should I add my modified code sample to either my original question or to your answer as an edit?

Comment: why not? refresh$.pipe(switchMap(() => yourObservable), shareReplay(1)) will work like that

Answer (score 0):

I think BehaivorSubject can resolve your problem without creating new observable, but I would advise using ngrx or mobx to work with data, is much more convenient. And I cant uderstand why you set data is private and create getter? normal practice to use public for variables in a view.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {
  private url = 'http://mydummydomain.com/api/entries';
  public data$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
      take(1)
    ).subscribe((data) => {
      this.data$.next(data);
    });
  }
  
  reloadData() {
    this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
      take(1)
    ).subscribe((data) => {
      this.data$.next(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Its better to move your logic with API to the service, you can use the data in several components and you can use it more efficiently when the data is stored in one place.

Comment: I have been trying to test this solution, but it does seem to be working. Do components need to subscribe to the data$ property? I keep getting the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Comment: Getting data from the API is an asynchronous action, for the first time data$ will be null, add a null check to the component (for example, `*ngIf="!(data $ | async)"`)
Subscribing to observevable items in the component is not a problem,
just do not forget to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy (in our case, I use take (1) to get the first value from api and unsubscribe)